# Dynamically added fields are adding random sequence-JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, dynamic

I have a Button which adds a set of Text fields whenever i Click on **Add More** button.
Actually what happens is that whenever i Add new text fields it get appended above the **Add More** button, and when i press again that button it Adds the text fields above the text fields which were added recently.

It Must get added exact above the **Add More ** button not above the, recently added text fields.

Below is my code , jst check where i am going wrong

*new.php*

```
. . . . . 


<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-24">
    <div class="input_fields" style="color:black">
         <button class="add_field btn " onclick="incrementValue()" >Add More</button>
         <div>
         <input type="text" name="mytextt[]" hidden="" ></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


. . . . . . . 



<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field"); //Add button ID
    var wrapper_pre1         = $(".present_fields_1"); //Fields wrapper
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();

        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
           $(wrapper).prepend('<br><div style="margin-left:50%;"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label type" for="selectbasic" style="">Type of work</label><div class="col-md-6"><select id="type_of_work[]" name="type_of_work[]" class="form-control type_of_work" style=""><option value="Audit Report">Audit Report</option><option value="ITR filing">ITR filing</option><option value="VAT Filing">VAT Filing</option><option value="Accounting">Accounting</option><option value="Registration">Registration</option><option value="Certification">Certification</option><option value="Others">Others</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label status" for="selectbasic" style="">Status</label><div class="col-md-6"><select id="status1' + x + '"  name="status[]"  class="form-control status"><option value="Pending">Pending</option><option value="Work in process">Work in process</option><option value="Completed">Completed</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="example-date-input" class="col-2 col-form-label date">DATE</label><div class="col-10 col"><input class="form-control datepicker pickers" id="date" name="date[]" style="" type="text" readonly></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label comment" for="textinput" style="">Comment</label><div class="col-md-4"><input id="comments' + x + '" name="comment[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md comment" style=""></div></div></center><a href="#" class="remove_field" style=""><img src="images/del24.png" ></a></a></div>'); //add input box\
          var newInput=$("#date").datepick({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});
          newInput.datepick({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'}).datepick("setDate", new Date());
          $("#status1" + x).click(function () {

            if ($("#status1" + x).val() == "Completed") {
                $("#comments" + x).attr("required", "required");
            }
            else
              $("#comments" + x).attr("required", false);
        });

      }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })

    $(wrapper_pre1).on("click",".remove_field_pre1", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })

  });


</script>
```

As you can see the below image , in the Comment field i have added numbers just for refrence how it gets added , want the sequence to be as above **Add More** button but its getting added at the top [image: Screenshot]

Thank you in advance !

Comment: When you insert the new group of fields, just add it to the end of the container div for all the field groups. Append instead of prepend....

Comment: @SloanThrasher No but when i do that the Add More button goes up as and when a new filed is added

Comment: Then move the add more button outside the container for the field groups. or add a containing div around the field groups that ends before the add more button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your template differently. Instead of

```
$(wrapper).prepend('<br><div style="marg (...) of ></a></a></div>')
```

add it like this

```
$('<br><div style="marg (...) of ></a></a></div>').insertBefore(add_button)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field"); //Add button ID
    var wrapper_pre1         = $(".present_fields_1"); //Fields wrapper
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();

        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
           $(wrapper).append('<br><div style="margin-left:50%;"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label type" for="selectbasic" style="">Type of work</label><div class="col-md-6"><select id="type_of_work[]" name="type_of_work[]" class="form-control type_of_work" style=""><option value="Audit Report">Audit Report</option><option value="ITR filing">ITR filing</option><option value="VAT Filing">VAT Filing</option><option value="Accounting">Accounting</option><option value="Registration">Registration</option><option value="Certification">Certification</option><option value="Others">Others</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label status" for="selectbasic" style="">Status</label><div class="col-md-6"><select id="status1' + x + '"  name="status[]"  class="form-control status"><option value="Pending">Pending</option><option value="Work in process">Work in process</option><option value="Completed">Completed</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="example-date-input" class="col-2 col-form-label date">DATE</label><div class="col-10 col"><input class="form-control datepicker pickers" id="date" name="date[]" style="" type="text" readonly></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-4 control-label comment" for="textinput" style="">Comment</label><div class="col-md-4"><input id="comments' + x + '" name="comment[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md comment" style=""></div></div></center><a href="#" class="remove_field" style=""><img src="images/del24.png" ></a></a></div>'); //add input box\
          

      }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })

    $(wrapper_pre1).on("click",".remove_field_pre1", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-24">
    <div class="input_fields" style="color:black">
         
         <div>
         <input type="text" name="mytextt[]" hidden="" ></div>
</div>
<button class="add_field btn " onclick="" >Add More</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually @Nobita it getting added both above  and below of Add More Button